# Unhandled exception at location :Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location

Tags: c++, class, header-files

There haven't really been any answers that I could understand after looking through the questions that were previously asked on this subject.  My TA tried to help me with this for about an hour and couldn't figure anything out.

First of all, this is where the error takes me when the program compiles

In xthrow.cpp

```
_CRTIMP2_PURE __declspec(noreturn) void __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL
_Xlength_error(_In_z_ const char * _Message)
{ // report a length_error
_THROW_NCEE(length_error, _Message);
}
```

In dbgmalloc.c

```
void *res = _nh_malloc_dbg(nSize, _newmode, _NORMAL_BLOCK, NULL, 0);
```

Header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class matrix
{   
private:
    vector <vector <double> > mat;      // Stores 2D matrices
    int nRows;                      // Stores number of rows
    int nCols;                      // Stores number of columns
    void resize(int nRows, int nCols);          // Resizes mat      

public:
    void readfile(ifstream&);           // Reads values for nRows and nCols
    matrix(ifstream&);                  // Calls readfile function
    void print();                       // Prints the current values of mat
    int getrows();                      // Returns the value of nRows
    int getcols();                      // Returns the value of nColumns
    vector<vector<double>> getmat();        // Returns a 2D vector
    void add(matrix);                   // Adds 2 matrices and stores in mat 
    // Multiplies 2 matrices and stores in mat
    vector<vector<double>> multiply(matrix);
};
```

function file

```
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

void matrix::resize(int nRows, int nCols)
{
    mat.resize(nRows);
    for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
    {
        mat[i].resize(nCols);
    }
}

void matrix::readfile(ifstream& input_file)
{

input_file >> nRows >> nCols;

resize(nRows, nCols);

for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<nCols; j++)
    {
        input_file >> mat[i][j];
    }
}
}

matrix::matrix(ifstream& input_file)
{
    readfile(input_file);
}

void matrix::print()
{
for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<nCols; j++)
    {
        cout << mat[i][j] << '\t';
    }
cout << endl;
}

}
```

main

```
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream input_file;
string filename;
//int nRows;
//int nCols;

cout << "Enter filename: " << endl;
cin >> filename;
cout << '\n';

input_file.open(filename.c_str());
if (input_file.fail())
{
    cout << "file didn't open.";
    system("pause");
}
else
{
//input_file >> nRows >> nCols;
//cout << "Matrix 1:" << endl << "Rows = " << getrows() << endl;
//cout << "Columns = " << nCols << '\n' << endl;

matrix a(input_file);
a.print();
system("pause");
}
return 0;
}
```

Sorry the format is a little nasty.  It is difficult to copy and paste code into this...  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like your TA needs a bit of teaching. Specifically, how to use a debugger to avoid wasting an hour on a simple bug.

Comment: yeah i agree with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void matrix::readfile(ifstream& input_file)
{
resize(nRows, nCols);
for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<nCols; j++)
    {
        input_file >> mat[i][j];
    }
}
}

matrix::matrix(ifstream& input_file)
{
    readfile(input_file);
}
```

When `matrix` is constructed, `resize()` is called with *uninitialized* `nRows` and `nCols`. This leads to incorrect values fed into `std::vector::resize()`.

Per your description in comments, you should add the following line in the beginning of `matrix::readfile()`:

```
input_file >> nRows >> nCols;
```

Comment: Not sure how to initialize it here.  The value should be initialized in the main file, but maybe I'm missing something.  this is our first week doing classes so I am having trouble with the syntax a little and where to include things.  I uncommented the nRows and nCols parts of the main file (after else), and this didn't resolve it.

Comment: It depends on how you specify the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have included that.  The first two values in the files that I am using are the dimensions of the matrix.  Rows, then columns, then the values of the matrix.

Comment: So I added that and it gives me the same error.  Did I add it in the correct place (i revised the code in my question)?  Sorry, I am really new at this and my TAs aren't super helpful...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had someone help with debugging and I was pulling the values for nRows and nCols twice so it gave a negative number for the resize function and that obviously failed.